# Toplevel window without root one

Tags: python, tkinter

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

button = tk.Button(root, text = 'run')
button.pack()

def run2():
    new_root = tk.Toplevel()
    new_root.geometry("400x500")

    label = tk.Label(new_root, text="This is new root")
    label.pack()

    root.destroy()

    new_root.mainloop()

button.config(command = run2)

root.mainloop()
```

I want to create a `Toplevel` window, but also want to destroy the root one. but I am unable to do it.

Comment: Call `root.destroy()` first and then use `tk.Tk()` instead of `tk.Toplevel()`.

Comment: Ok so you are saying , Toplevel is the part of the root window, if we destroy it then it will destroy our toplevel window also.

Comment: Yes I am writing an answer right now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you destroy a `tk.Tk()`, you also distroy all of the widgets/`Toplevel`s associated with that window.

To solve your problem you have 2 options:

- Use `root.withdraw()` instead of `root.destroy()`. That will hide the window instead of destroying it. Please note that it will still take up memory and computational power.
- Call `root.destroy()` first then create a brand new window using `new_root = tk.Tk()`. If you use this approach, you wouldn't be able to get your original window back. And your function will look like this:

```py
def run2():
    root.destroy() # Destroy the old window

    new_root  = tk.Tk() # Create the new window
    new_root.geometry("400x500")

    label = tk.Label(new_root, text="This is new root")
    label.pack()

    # new_root.mainloop() # Unneeded - @acw1668
```

Comment: Thanks for this discussion, i was just having a doubt about the toplevel window but now I'm clear.

Comment: The `tk.Topwindow()` is technically a part of the `tk.Tk()`. You can't have a `Toplevel` without a `Tk`. Glad that I can help

Comment: `new_root.mainloop()` is not necessary.

Comment: @acw1668 True but it doesn't hurt. Also it was part of OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to create a toplevel window, but also want to destroy the root one. but i am not able to do it.

That is correct: you are not able to do it.

A fundamental aspect of tkinter is that widgets live in a hierarchy, and that hierarchy must have a root node. If you destroy any node in the tree, all child nodes are automatically deleted. Thus, if you destroy the root window then all children of the root will also be deleted.

There is no way around this fact -- there must be a root window. You can hide it from view, but it still must exist.